# New main PID does not belong to service, and PID file is not owned by root

Tags: systemd, remote-desktop, vnc

When running vncserver (tightvncserver) on Xubuntu 18.04 as a service, I get this error

> New main PID 2095 does not belong to service, and PID file is not owned by root. Refusing.

My service file looks like this

```
/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service 

[Unit]
Description=Start TightVNC server at startup
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=user
PAMName=login
PIDFile=/home/user/.vnc/%H:%i.pid
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i > /dev/null 2>&1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver -depth 24 -geometry 1280x800 :%i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

According to [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1583159) bug report, it has something to do with [this](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/db256aab13d8a89d583ecd2bacf0aca87c66effc) change in systemd.

Any suggestions on updating my service file so it works with systemd again?

Answer (score 8):

You're probably referencing the [16.04 version of this Digital Ocean VNC guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04) rather than the [18.04 version](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-18-04). In the 18.04 version the `/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service` file should look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start TightVNC server at startup
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=sammy
Group=sammy
WorkingDirectory=/home/sammy

PIDFile=/home/sammy/.vnc/%H:%i.pid
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i > /dev/null 2>&1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver -depth 24 -geometry 1280x800 :%i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Remember to replace all 4 instances of `sammy` with your own user name. The 18.04 version fixed my issues with the same *PID file is not owned by root* errors that you reported.

Answer (score 2):

Commenting out `PAMName=login` solved the issue on 16.04